# Coupled Complex Differential Eqauation with complex constant

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, differential, several-complex-variables

I have the following system of complex differential equations
$$ \frac{dA}{dz} = K_{ab}Be^{-i\Delta z}$$
$$ \frac{dB}{dz} = K_{ba}Ae^{i\Delta z}$$
where A,B,$K_{ab}$,$K_{ba}$ are complex, with initial conditions A(0)=0, B(0) = $B_{0}$ and $K_{ab} = -K_{ba}^*$. The first thing I do is take derivative of first equation with respect to z.
Then I have in simplified form
$$\frac{d^2A}{dz^2} = K_{ab}K_{ba}A-i\Delta \frac{dA}{dz} $$
$$\frac{d^2A}{dz^2} + i\Delta \frac{dA}{dz} + |K_{ab}|^2A = 0 $$

I couldn't proceed with success, assuming this second order equation has the solution in the form of $e^{sz}$. The discriminant of characteristic polynomial is less than zero and roots are not conjugate of each other. I have looked Arfken Mathematical Methods but I couldn't see the solution. Thanks in advance I am open to any textbook advice on complex differential equations

Comment: "The discriminant of characteristic polynomial is less than zero and roots are not conjugate of each other" - why is this a problem?

Comment: In the case of real constant coefficients, if discriminant < 0 then we have complex conjugate roots and we write complex and real parts separately and get a solution in the form of cos and sin. Here, I thought may be that also works but it isnt indeed. The ''assumed'' didnt satisfy the differential equation

Answer (score 0):

$e^{isz}$ solves the differential equation but I am not satisfied, since I found it by trial and error.